# Prevent HTML flash on TinyMCE load

Tags: tinymce

My question is the same as [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512866/other-content-seen-and-blinks-during-tinymce-loading), I want to prevent the brief flash of HTML that happens on a page with a TinyMCE editor. The problem with the answer to that other Stackoverflow question is that it does not seem to work with TinyMCE 4. I set `display:none;` of the textarea containing the HTML to edit. And in the init callback for TinyMCE, I reset it to `display:block;`. All that happens is that the original textarea is displayed on the page, with no sign of the TinyMCE editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the visibility property instead.